# Get value from nested functions in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, nested, anonymous-function

i want to get a result from another function (anonymous-function), but i don't know how because my result-function is a nested function. Maybe I have to use a callback somehow?
Here my code:

```
render: ->
    console.log @getCommunities()
    return this

getCommunities: ->
    dpd.communities.get (result, err) ->
        return console.log(err)  if err
        result
```

getCommunities() returns always 'undefined'.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks,
rojan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
render: ->
    @getCommunities (err, result) ->
       if err then throw err
       console.log result
    return this

getCommunities: (callback) ->
    dpd.communities.get (result, err) ->
        return console.log(err)  if err
        callback(null, result)
```

fyi, it's a best practice to pass `err` as the first arg to callbacks in node, assuming this is in fact node...just guessing by the err callback